# numberOfLines of UILabel doesn't work within cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel, ios6

All,

I am very new to iphone programming. In the following code, I want the text to show all of the text within the comment label but right now it is truncating it.  numberofLines is not working right either.  Right now it is doing this. "My name is Fred and I aint dead..."  but I want it to display the full text "My name is Fred and I aint dead yet so let me live" even if it has to be on multiple lines.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 80.0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

cell = [self.allCells objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

if(!cell)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserCell2" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [self.allCells setObject:cell forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
}

GSAsynImageView *imgView = (GSAsynImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
UILabel *lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
UILabel *lblComment = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1003];
UILabel *lbltime = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1004];

//lblComment setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
//lblComment.numberOfLines = 0;
//lblComment.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;

if(self.arrComments.count==0)
{
    imgView.hidden = YES;
    lblTitle.text = nil;
    lblComment.text = nil;
    lbltime.text = nil;
    if(indexPath.row==1)lblTitle.text = @"No comments yet";
}
else
{
    imgView.hidden = NO;

    NSDictionary *dcUser = [self.arrComments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *strBio = [dcUser objectForKey:@"CommentTxt"];
    NSString *strDisplayName = [dcUser objectForKey:@"CommenterDisplayName"];

    NSString *imgName = [dcUser objectForKey:@"ImageName"];
    NSString *usernamex = [dcUser objectForKey:@"CommenterUserName"];

    if([imgName isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        if([imgName rangeOfString:@"facebook"].location!=NSNotFound || [imgName rangeOfString:@"twimg"].location!=NSNotFound)
            [imgView loadImageFromPath:imgName];
        else
            [imgView loadImageFromPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@images/%c/%@/50x50%@",WEBSERVER,[usernamex characterAtIndex:0],usernamex,imgName]];
    }

    lblTitle.text = strDisplayName;
    lblComment.text = strBio;
    lbltime.text = [self getDateTitle:[dcUser objectForKey:@"Date"]];

}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: You should use UITextView to show the multiple lines instead of UIlabel

Comment: Make sure that your label has enough vertical space, or it will truncate it even if you set multiple lines.

Comment: Increase the width of label & then check with no. of lines= 0...

Comment: That's not true. :P ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this bellow code and add in your cell..

```
UILabel * lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];
[lblTitle setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 31, 200, 50)];        
lblTitle.text = @"your Text ";
lblTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;// add this line 
lblTitle.numberOfLines = 0;// add this  line
lblTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
```

for more detail see my blog with this post from [THIS](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/11/set-uilabel-with-adjust-content-text.html) link

Comment: `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` is now deprecated - use `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` instead.

Comment: In Swift3 use .byWordWrapping

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x , cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    label.text = @" Text to be displayed in label ";
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap ;// Wrap at word boundaries
    label.numberOfLines = 0;// this line include multiple lines
    [cell addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it probably because the size of the string you wanna show on the label exceeds the size of that label

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties of UILabel to increase the number of lines.
Like `UILabel* para = [[UILabel alloc]init];`

```
para.numberoOfLines = 10;
```

and also try changing `para.lineBreakMode`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is in a storyboard or xib. You can add your label (and anything else you want) to the custom cell you get automatically when you have a table view. Make sure your label has a specific width set, and that it has constraints to the top and bottom of the cell (make sure you set number of lines to 0). If you have these, the label will expand with the height of the cell, which you set in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the height of the label and make the number of line to 2 for the particular label.

try this code,

```
lblComment.numberofLines = 2; 
[lblComment setFrame:CGRectMake(100,20,200,70)];
```